# Batch file to search a string and then edit it

Tags: batch-file, batch-updates

Sample input:

```
<document> 
 <filename>Admin Training Manual.pdf</filename>
 <type>0</type>
</document>
<document>
 <filename>Document Manual.pdf</filename>
 <type>0</type>
</document>
```

Condition:
If the filename is = Admin Training Manual, change the type to 1.

Output:

```
<document> 
 <filename>Admin Training Manual.pdf</filename>
 <type>1</type>
</document>
<document>
 <filename>Document Manual.pdf</filename>
 <type>0</type>
</document>
```

I have tried everything on my disposal and cant find any answer.

I have not yet attempted but the concept is there:

```
if header = <document> (
  loop to count line inside <document>
    if line is equal to 1 
    then check the string
      if match
      then replace line 2 with 1.     
)
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include your best attempt so far so we have something to start with.

Comment: Doing this properly in batch is quite complicated.  Can you rely on your input being formatted like this, and do you need to parse the XML hierarchy?  *ie* is it sufficient to assume that there's one tag per line?

Comment: I have placed my algorithm. Does that seem valid?

Comment: There are the other questions?  I'll add my own - are there any blank lines in the file?  Do they need to be preserved?

Comment: No blank lines. They have a uniform format.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "src=<filename>Admin Training Manual.pdf</filename>"
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.xml) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    if "!line!"=="!src!" set "flag=true"
    if not "!line:<type>=!"=="!line!" if defined flag (
        set "flag="
        set "line=<type>1</type>"
    )
    echo(!line!
    for /f %%b in ('set "flag" 2^>nul') do (if "!"=="" endlocal)&set "%%b"
))>out.xml
```

Comment: Not tested and maybe i'm wrong, but, will not `endlocal` cancel the assignment of flag, so it is always undefined when `<type>` line is readed? Also, no need for delayed expansion in `!src!`

Comment: The script did place an output but it did not check correctly the condition thus skipping the tag <type>

Comment: What does the ! before the !line! and the !src! do?

Comment: @MCND - concerning the flag: why do you think so about my code? And delayed expansion makes no harm to !src! and I always get nervous with so much poison characters  :)

Comment: @user3006461 and moreover `what does the fox say`  :)

Comment: @Endoro: The sequence `setlocal`, `set "flag=true"`, `endlocal` does not make changes to `flag` variable vanish between passes of the `for` loop? So, when the `src` line is seen, flag is set, but then endlocal is executed and changes to flag are lost. When the `type` line is readed, flag is undefined and `type` line is not changed.

Comment: @MCND omg: you are right! and usually I know this :facepalm: /made an edit. THX.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"<filename>Admin Training Manual.pdf</filename>" input.txt') do set /A num=%%a+1

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" input.txt') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if %%a equ %num% set "line=!line:0=1!"
   echo !line!
)) > output.txt
```